# How to mount new disk after reaching the 2TB limit Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, diskspace

I am doing large data processing on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) but have run into disk storage issues overnight.

**1) My disk size has hit the limit of 2TB:**

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.1G   11M  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       2.0T  1.9T     0 100% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

**2) I increased (naively) the disk size to 3TB**

```
sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   3T  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   2T  0 part /
```

**3) and tried to grow the disk size**

```
sudo growpart /dev/sda 1
NOCHANGE: partition 1 could only be grown by 1 [fudge=2048]
```

but I cannot grow it.

**Question:**

How can I use the extra 1TB from the 3TB disk? Any better ways to make use of the extra 1TB for my project are much appreciated.

Note: I am a newbie to GCP and do not understand it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have mount the new persistent disk? You should see it with lsblk command.
[This page)(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) can help you to perform the required steps

- Create a partition and format it
  `sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/sdb`
- Create your directory where to mount the partition
  `mkdir -p /path/to/mount/`
- Mount the partition
  `sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb /path/to/mount`

Don't forget to update the right on the directory with a `chmod` according with your security policy

Then, use standard linux command to copy/move files/directory in the new directory where your persistent disk is mounted
I recommend you to let the app running on the boot disk and to store the data on the persistent disk.

***Don't forget to follow the tutorial until the fstab update for an automatic disk mount at VM startup***

Comment: `sda      8:0    0    3T  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0    2T  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 1000G  0 disk /disks2`  Thanks for the video. I will definitely watch it. Yes, I am running the app on `sda1` while the new persistent disk is `sdb`

Comment: Yes, you have to mount the disk. However, I recommend you to size it enough for all your data. It's not a good idea to fragment them, for the software simplicity, for the recovery in case of failure,..

Comment: How do I copy data from `sda1` to `sdb`? The new disk is already mounted.

Comment: Hello @code123, since the disk is already mounted, you can use either `cp -a` or `rsync`. More details [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=175236).

Comment: I updated my answer. For me, the challenge is to mount the disk. Then, it's simply linux file management. Do you have a challenge on this part ? What is the blocking point ?

Comment: @guillahme Thanks a lot. I was able to copy the data as advised. It's simply Linux commands thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach additional disk. 2 solutions: local SSD and persistent disk.

Local SSD are ephemeral storage. The disk are empty when the instance start but the performance are incredible. You can attach up to 8 disk of 375go.

The other solution is to attach persistent disk. Slower but with high resiliency and backup. Max 64to per disk. And, in beta, you can attach up to 128 disks to a 8vCPU (or more) instance. Else Max 16 disks in GA

Here how to attach a persistent disk:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk?hl=fr

You should have enough!!!

Comment: Thank you both. I was able to create a new persistent disk and mount it. Now, how do I move data off the booting drive onto the new drive as suggested by @John Hanley? My two drives are `/dev/sda1`and `/dev/sda`. I want to copy data and store it in the later to free up space in the former where I am doing the computations.