# How do I shrink boot disk size?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm new-ish to GCP and this is the first time I've run into a need to downsize a disk.

Background: I resized my boot disk from 1.5 TB to 12 TB to download a lot of data for a research project. But it turns out that the boot disk has an MBR partition type, which according to the GCP docs means "the maximum size of such disk would be 2 TB". Now I cannot use 10 TB out of 12 TB despite paying for it...

I created an additional disk of size 1.5 TB and used `rsync -avxP /old/ /new/` to copy all files from the old boot disk to the new disk. Then I unmounted the old disk and tried to start the VM with the new disk as boot disk. But I'm getting an SSH error and cannot access my VM:

> Code: 4003
> Reason: failed to
> connect to backend
>
> Please ensure that:
>
> - your user account has iap.tunnelInstances.accessViaIAP permission
> - VM has a firewall rule that allows TCP ingress traffic from the IP range xx.xxx.xxx.x/xx, port: 22
> - you can make a proper https connection to the IAP for TCP hostname: https://tunnel.cloudproxy.app You may be able to connect without using
>   the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.

Has anyone encountered this before? How can I either use the 10 TB or solve the SSH problem? Thanks.

I have followed the suggestions at

- [Google Cloud How to reduce disk size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731578/google-cloud-how-to-reduce-disk-size)
- [How to mount new disk after reaching the 2TB limit Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339479/how-to-mount-new-disk-after-reaching-the-2tb-limit-google-cloud)

but have not been able to resolve my issue.

Comment: You can't shrink disk. Create an image and then create a smallest disk with that image

Comment: Yes, I know that you can't shrink disks. If I create an image of the VM, won't the image now contain the 12TB disk? What do you mean by "create a smallest disk with that image"?